# Integration by parts of a double integral

Tags: integration

$$M = -\int \int \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \, x \, dx\, dy \, -\int \int 
    \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \, y \, dx\, dy \, $$
Here $\phi$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. $M$ is some quantity. We need to integrate by parts the right hand side of the above equation.
Given that
$$\phi = 0$$
at the boundary. Here is the region:
[region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSvt9.png)

Finally the result is:
$$M = 2\int \int \phi \, dx \, dy$$
I want to know the intermediate steps in the integration.
I have tried like this:
$$M = -\int dy\int \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \, x \, dx \, - \, -\int dx\int \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} \, y \, dy$$
and separately:
$$\int x\, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\, dx = x\, \phi-\int\phi\, dx$$
$$\int y\, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\, dy = y\, \phi-\int\phi\, dy$$
Putting these back and using
$$\int \phi\, dx=0$$
$$\int \phi\, dy=0$$
we have
$$M = -\int x\, \phi\, dy\, -\int y\, \phi\, dx$$
After this I don't know how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Green formula would help IMO. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting these back should yield $M=-\int dy (-\int \phi dx)-\int dx(-\int \phi dy)=2\int \int\phi dx dy$ where You used the fact that $x\phi$ and $y\phi$ vanish on the boundary, since these terms are evaluated on the boundary using partial integration.

Comment: Okay the mistake in my post is that I have taken zero for the wrong terms.

Comment: Exactly, because the integrals are evaluated over the whole region while the other terms are evaluated over the boundary where $\phi$ vanishes and thus these terms, all this gets clearer if You have a closer look at Gauss theorem which is essentially the same as partial integration (as well as Greens formulas)

Comment: can this be simplified using Green's theorem in a plane?

Comment: Yes it can, in the end all these are consequences of Stoke´s theorem. If You feel more comfortable with Green´s theorem this is fine ( in this situation)